# Rails seems to be writing console output to /var/log/httpd/error_log

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, passenger

I'm using passenger and apache, and my error logs are filing up fast. The message does start with `stderr`, but this is the same info I get in the console if I just run `rails s` from the directory the App is in when the app is accessed. This seems more like access_logs info to me.

Where is the rails log info setup at?

```
App 6571 stderr: 2014-03-10 13:51:07 -0400: GET http://localhost:9200/_search [status:200, request:0.381s, query:0.125s]
App 6571 stderr: 2014-03-10 13:51:07 -0400: > {"query":{"term":{"message":"drop"}},"size":15000,"fields":["message","@timestamp","type"]}
App 6571 stderr: 2014-03-10 13:51:07 -0400: < {"took":125,"timed_out":false,"_shards":{"total":195,"successful":195,"failed":0},"hits":{"total":183625,"max_score":17.807178,"hits":[{"_index":"logstash-2014.03.04","_type":"Cisco ASA","_id":"3fKyZ7jxTvGxdoNF_RVzuQ","_score":17.807178,"fields":{"type":"Cisco ASA","message":"<165>%ASA-5-304001: 192.168.1.136 Accessed URL 68.142.250.160:http://l1.yimg.com/zz/combo?yui:3.9.1/build/yui-throttle/yui-throttle-min.js&yui:3.9.1/build/dd-ddm-base/dd-ddm-base-min.js&yui:3.9.1/build/dd-drag/dd-drag-min.js&yui:3.9.1/build/dd-ddm/dd-ddm-min.js&yui:3.9.1/build/dd-ddm-drop/dd-ddm-drop-min.js&yui:3.9.1/build/dd-drop/dd-drop-min.js&yui:3.9.1/build/dd-drop-plugin/dd-drop-plugin-min.js&yui:3.9.1/build/dd-delegate/dd-delegate-min.js&yui:3.9.1/build/resize-base/resize-base-min.js&yui:3.9.1/build/<166>%ASA-6-305011: Built dynamic TCP translation from inside:192.168.1.136/59375 to outside:216.173.187.131/59375","@timestamp":"2014-03-04T17:59:11.236Z"}},{"_index":"logstash-2014.02.24","_type":"Cisco ASA","_id":"-WVWoezISV2QUfzu4hEILg","_score":17.679113,"fields":{"type":"Cisco ASA","message":"<165>%ASA-5-304001: 192.168.1.133 Accessed URL 68.142.250.160:http://l1.yimg.com/zz/combo?yui:3.9.1/build/yui-throttle/yui-throttle-min.js&yui:3.9.1/build/dd-ddm-base/dd-ddm-base-min.js&yui:3.9.1/build/dd-drag/dd-drag-min.js&yui:3.9.1/build/dd-ddm/dd-ddm-min.js&yui:3.9.1/build/dd-ddm-drop/dd-ddm-drop-min.js&yui:3.9.1/build/dd-drop/dd-drop-min.js&yui:3.9.1/build/dd-drop-plugin/dd-drop-plugin-min.js&yui:3.9.1/build/dd-delegate/dd-delegate-min.js&yui:3.9.1/build/resize-base/resize-base-min.js&yui:3.9.1/build/<166>%ASA-6-305011: Built dynamic UDP translation from inside:192.168.1.46/60529 to outside:216.173.187.131/60529","@timestamp":"2014-02-24T22:09:03.165Z"}},{"_index":"logstash-2014.02.25","_type":"Cisco ASA","_id":"1WsPKOs-QVKLkemYrUMmgQ","_score":17.666998,"fields":{"type":"Cisco ASA","message":"<165>%ASA-5-304001: 192.168.1.120 Accessed URL 68.142.250.160:http://l1.yimg.com/zz/combo?yui:3.9.1/build/yui-throttle/yui-throttle-min.js&yui:3.9.1/build/dd-ddm-base/dd-ddm-base-min.js&yui:3.9.1/build/dd-drag/dd-drag-min.js&yui:3.9.1/build/dd-ddm/dd-ddm-min.js&yui:3.9.1/build/dd-ddm-drop/dd-ddm-drop-min.js&yui:3.9.1/build/dd-drop/dd-drop-min.js&yui:3.9.1/build/dd-drop-plugin/dd-drop-plugin-min.js&yui:3.9.1/build/dd-delegate/dd-delegate-min.js&yui:3.9.1/build/resize-base/resize-base-min.js&yui:3.9.1/build/<166>%ASA-6-302016: Teardown UDP connection 30032834 for outside:208.67.222.222/53 to inside:192.168.1.46/60075 duration 0:00:00 bytes 204","@timestamp":"2014-02-25T20:25:22.420Z"}},{"_index":"logstash-2014.03.06","_type":"Cisco ASA","_id":"LFp3qOJ8QRazMhCNy-0nGw","_score":17.543964,"fields":{"type":"Cisco ASA","message":"<165>%ASA-5-304001: 192.168.1.116 Accessed URL 68.142.250.160:http://l1.yimg.com/zz/combo?yui:3.9.1/build/yui-throttle/yui-throttle-min.js&yui:3.9.1/build/dd-ddm-base/dd-ddm-base-min.js&yui:3.9.1/build/dd-drag/dd-drag-min.js&yui:3.9.1/build/dd-ddm/dd-ddm-min.js&yui:3.9.1/build/dd-ddm-drop/dd-ddm-drop-min.js&yui:3.9.1/build/dd-drop/dd-drop-min.js&yui:3.9.1/build/dd-drop-plugin/dd-drop-plugin-min.js&yui:3.9.1/build/dd-delegate/dd-delegate-min.js&yui:3.9.1/build/resize-base/resize-base-min.js&yui:3.9.1/build/<165>%ASA-5-415008: HTTP - matched Class 22: LogDomainsClass in policy-map http_inspection_policy, header matched from inside:192.168.1.116/51359 to outside: 68.142.250.141/80","@timestamp":"2014-03-06T14:19:48.318Z"}},{"_index":"logstash-2014.03.03","_type":"Cisco ASA","_id":"cNtnivFvQp2GYCHK5RmZMA","_score":17.535679,"fields":{"type":"Cisco ASA","message":"<165>%ASA-5-304001: 192.168.1.183 Accessed URL 68.142.250.141:http://l1.yimg.com/zz/combo?yui:3.9.1/build/yui-throttle/yui-throttle-min.js&yui:3.9.1/build/dd-ddm-base/dd-ddm-base-min.js&yui:3.9.1/build/dd-drag/dd-drag-min.js&yui:3.9.1/build/dd-ddm/dd-ddm-min.js&yui:3.9.1/build/dd-ddm-drop/dd-ddm-drop-min.js&yui:3.9.1/build/dd-drop/dd-drop-min.js&yui:3.9.1/build/dd-drop-plugin/dd-drop-plugin-min.js&yui:3.9.1/build/dd-delegate/dd-delegate-min.js&yui:3.9.1/buil
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the [documentation at Phusion Passenger's site](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#_passengerdebuglogfile_lt_filename_gt), you can change the location via the `PassengerDebugLogFile` option in Apache.